# how to add a picture on the back of an html body and in the back of a list using jQuery mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

i am starting to learn client web programing using phonegap and jquery mobile and while reading some toturials i searched for a way to add a pic to the back of a list but didnt find one.
also while adding a pic to the top of a page i got a problem in the page scaling, what i did was adding a img html tag with the align center... and it is working but when viewing on the smart phone the picture does not scale to screen size...is there a simple way to make it do so?

i am sorry if my questions may be trivial but i just started and i am doing a class project...

thanks!
moshe bn

Answer (score 1):

That's what the CSS [`background`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background) property is for.

```
ul {
    background: url(images/image.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: thanks! what are the zeros parameters for?

Comment: [`background-position`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-position) - `left top` would be equivalent for `0 0`.

Comment: it seems like that this option does not work on the list for some reason....  i used : <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="background: url('couponsSignFixed.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;">

Comment: You may have to specify a `min-width` and a `min-height`

Comment: i am sorry i wasnt specific enough.. i meant that when doing the about the pic is not visable at all.

Comment: are is an example to the kind of page i want with the upper pic sitting perfect on web browser and mobile web browser alike : http://m.opentable.com/

Comment: Images in your CSS are relative to the location of your CSS document. For instance, if your CSS is in `example.com/styles/stylesheet.css` and your images are in `example.com/images/image.jpg`, you reference the image by `url(../images/image.jpg)`. If you want your list to look like the open-table one, you might need to specify some [`padding`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/padding) to the top of the list.

Answer (score 0):

for images I would recommend against scaling them because there are so many different screen sizes. You probably don't want your image to end up looking pixelated and weird.

Have you used @media queries before? [This is a good article](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) and you might find that it is better to have a few different sized versions of your image that you can show depending on the amount of space your user's device screen allows.

Comment: thank you. i will try learning this but now i need a quick solution for my project